# Watin 2.1 error with Firefox 3.6 ContainsText and jssh

Tags: firefox, automated-tests, watin

I have had problems using Firefox with Watin 2.0 and the recent 2.1 release.

- FireFox: 3.6.17
- Watin: 2.1.0.1196
- Gallio / mbUnit: 3.2.601
- Windows Server 2008 32 bit
- .NET 4.0 assemblies
- Visual Studio 2010

I went over these instructions repeatedly:
http://watin.org/documentation/setting-up-firefox/

I went to Firefox, File->Open, navigated to the file: **jssh-3.6-WINNT.xpi**

Installed the XPI in Firefox without any problem.

A few things do work fine in FF with Watin.  Finding text fields, TypeText, Click, all that works.  But this line of code blows up:

Assert.IsTrue(theBrowser.ContainsText(validationText), "Listing '{0}' was not found in the results.", validationText);

See below for the error.  Any idea what I did wrong?

```
WatiN.Core.Native.Mozilla.FireFoxException: Error sending last message to jssh server: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
C:\QEDev\tools\WatiN\source\src\Core\Native\Mozilla\FireFoxClientPort.cs(422,0): at WatiN.Core.Native.Mozilla.FireFoxClientPort.CheckForError(String response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another user here on StackOverflow answered this question in a separate thread.  Here is one workaround:

- Sub-class based off of Watin's Firefox class
- Override the ContainsText method
- Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to load the document and call the Contains method.

This seemed to work fine for a while.  On other computers I saw the same JSSH error as before.

```
public override bool ContainsText(string text)
{
    WaitForComplete();

    var htmldoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmldoc.LoadHtml(Html);

    bool result = htmldoc.DocumentNode.InnerText.Contains(text);

    return result;
}
```